# Displaying multiple datasets within SSRS from a single stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a single stored procedure which produces a number of result sets.

In short, the sp matches source records to a database of some 2 million plus accounts. The matching is performed on a number of key fields and the results are then used to obtain other details about the matched accounts before producing a number of result sets. The whole process can take minutes to hours depending upon the number of records in the source to be matched.

I am wanting to deliver a report in SSRS showing all the result sets.

However...

I am aware that SSRS will only return the first result set from the sp.

I am also aware of the two resolutions to get around this problem. These are 1) split the stored procedure up into multiple stored procs and 2) to UNION the result sets and place a filter in the datasets in SSRS.

In my case, neither of the two resolutions above are suitable. Splitting the sp is not an option due to the length of time it takes to perform the matching (eg I can't be performing matching for multiple sp). UNION is also not realistic as I have summary result sets and detail result sets containing varying datatypes and anything from a few columns up to 100 columns.

I would really like some alternative suggestions how I may convert this stored procedure that returns multiple result sets into a report on SSRS. Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question to provide a finite answer however it is clear that waiting an hour for a report to generate would not be acceptable.

You need to create "cubes" of data which will allow your reports to run quickly. your "cubes" of data need to reflect the potential different parameters which can be passed.

I enclose the word "cubes" in quotes because you can do this formally - see SSIS and SSAS or you can just build an informal data warehouse each night using some SQL.